# C++ Issue Using Getline

Tags: c++, getline

I'm trying to create a program in which the user can enter a series of player names and scores and read them back. However, I'm having trouble storing their input using getline. On getline in the InputData function, visual studio states, "Error: no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list          argument types are: (std::istream, char)", and on ==, it says, "Error: operand types are incompatible ("char" and "const char *")". Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int InputData(string [], int [], int);
void DisplayPlayerData(string [], int [], int);

void main()
{
    string playerNames[100];
    int scores[100];

    int sizeOfArray = sizeof(scores);
    int sizeOfEachElement = sizeof(scores[0]);
    int numberOfElements = sizeOfArray / sizeOfEachElement;

    cout << numberOfElements;

    int numberEntered = InputData(playerNames, scores, numberOfElements);

    DisplayPlayerData(playerNames, scores, numberOfElements);

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}

int InputData(string playerNames, int scores[], int size)
{
    int index;


    for (index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        cout << "Enter Player Name (Q to quit): ";
        getline(cin, playerNames[index]);
        if (playerNames[index] == "Q")
        {
            break;
        }
        cout << "Enter score: ";
        cin >> scores[index];
    }

    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int InputData(string playerNames, int scores[], int size)`

should be

`int InputData(string playerNames[], int scores[], int size)`

---

In your code, you pass `playerNames` as a string instead of a string array.

In `getline(cin, playerNames[index]);` `playerNames[index]` is a char, because `playerNames` is a string.

Comment: Yep, this was what I did wrong. Thank you very much.

Comment: My pleasure :) @jackofblaze

Comment: I have a further question about another problem with my getline, should I ask here or start a new question about it? I'm just having trouble with the getline skipping any user input after the first time it runs, and doing this until it gets through all of the array elements.

Comment: I think you should start a new question, because you can describe the question in details and attract more people.@jackofblaze

Answer (score 1):

> *Error: no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list argument types are: (std::istream, char)"*

This means that you are passing a single *char* value to `getline()` instead of the entire *string*. You do this in:

> ```
> getline(cin, playerNames[index])
> ```

You pass `playernames` as a string variable instead of a `sting[]` array. So, when you do `playernames[index]`, you are trying to pass **a single char value** to the function.

Judging from the code in your `main()` function, you want to pass an ***array*** of strings to the function, not *just* an individual string.

Therefore, change the arguments of `InputData()`

```
int InputData(string playerNames, int scores[], int size)
```

To:

```
int InputData(string playerNames[], int scores[], int size)
```

***@Pinky beat me to posting the answer first :), but I wanted to provide some more details, so I've posted my answer.*

**Another thing**, aside from your main question that I wanted to just point out, you should change the return data type of your `main()` function to `int main()` from `void main()`.

Answer (score 0):

i might be wrong because it's been a really long time since i've used c++, but have you tried cin.getline instead of just getline?